# Python list append automation

Tags: python, list

I am looking to append i to list1 then list2 then list 3 and so on, I am using python

```
        for person in population_list: 
            counter = 0
            place = random.randint(1, 5)
            if person:
                while counter <= places:
                    if place == counter:
                        place{counter}.append(person)
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: Better show the expected result or else people will have gotten the wrong idea.

Comment: After you edited the code, it's now a completely different question. Seriously, don't do that. As a different question.

Comment: With "show the expected result" I did *not* mean "remove the example input".

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience created, I will make sure I wont do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't append the elements one by one, this is inefficient, just do copies:

```
main_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
list1 = main_list.copy()
list2 = main_list.copy()
list3 = main_list.copy()
```

If you can, use containers, this makes life easier:

```
lists = [main_list.copy() for _ in range(3)]
```

then access:

```
list[0]
list[1]
list[2]
```

##### edit: assign elements of a list to random buckets

```
population_list = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP')
places = {i: [] for i in range(1,6)}
for p in population_list:
    places[random.randint(1, 5)].append(p)
places
```

example output:

```
>>> places
{1: ['B', 'C', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'P'],
 2: ['A', 'N'],
 3: ['D'],
 4: ['I', 'O'],
 5: ['E']}

>>> places[2]
['A', 'N']
```

Comment: I am not looking for this particullary, this is not what I asked, the code is just an example mozway

Comment: @R0Best the conclusion is the same, use containers, dynamically affecting variable names is **bad practice**, this leads to hard to debug, error-prone code

Answer (score 0):

Then just loop over the lists:

```
main_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
list1,list2,list3 = [], [], []

for list in [list1,list2,list3]:
    list.extend(main_list)
```